# Convert dictionary to list with some data omitted

Tags: python, regex, list, dictionary

I'm trying to convert a dictionary of the format:

```
d = {'A1': ['a', 'a', 'A2 (A3-)', 'a'],
     'B1': ['b', 'b', 'B2 (B3-)', 'b'],
     'C1': ['c', 'c', 'C2 (C3)-', 'c']}
```

To a list of the form:

```
e = [['A1', 'A2', 'A3'], ['B1', 'B2', 'B3'], ['C1', 'C2', 'C3']]
```

I know I should use regex to get the A2 and A3 data, but I'm having trouble putting this all together...

Comment: Is that representative of the actual structure of your lists as dictionary values? Why do you need regex? It's the second index of each list and relatively easy to split. Can you give some representative, real, data?

Comment: Share pattern for your list

Comment: This is exactly representative of the dictionary. I thought I would need regex to separate the data with brackets and dashes.  I apologise if this is naive or stupid, I am an absolute beginner and would appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import re

regex = re.compile(r'(\w+) \((\w+)-.*')

# I suppose that you meant (C3-) and not (C3)-
d = {'A1': ['a', 'a', 'A2 (A3-)', 'a'], 'B1': ['b', 'b', 'B2 (B3-)', 'b'], 'C1': ['c', 'c', 'C2 (C3-)', 'c']}

out = []
for key, values_list in d.items():
    v2, v3 = regex.match(values_list[2]).groups()
    out.append([key, v2, v3])

print(out)
# [['C1', 'C2', 'C3'], ['B1', 'B2', 'B3'], ['A1', 'A2', 'A3']]
```

Note that the order is random, as your original dict is unordered.

Comment: Thanks very much. groups is what I was missing in my efforts.

Comment: You can shrink the for loop down to `out = [(key,)+regex.match(values_list[2]).groups() for key, values_list in d.items()]`